# How do I notate a proposition with multiple conditions?

Tags: propositional-calculus

Lets's say I have the predicates:

F(x) means x is even
G(x) means x is a prime number

and we take the universe of discourse to be the set of natural numbers N = {1,2,3,...}

How do I notate a proposition such as:
"Every number that is a prime number is even"

Would the following be correct?
∀G(x)∃N[F(x)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\forall{x\in\mathbb{N}}:{G(x)}\implies{F(x)}$$

Comment: This proposition is false, BTW (in case you were thinking otherwise).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I know it's false. :)

Comment: @Xenidious: You're welcome. Feel free to accept it by clicking on the V next to it :)